# How can I run a python command that would click on each link on a page and extract the title, content, and date for each link?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using this link: https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statements/2000/2000_index.html. I have a command that clicks on each link on the page and takes out all of the data, but I would like to convert this into a csv file and therefore need to run three different commands that would get me the title, paragraphs, and dates of each article on the page(so that they can be the columns in the excel sheet). I am having difficulties because this page does not have 'class' or 'id'. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Here is my current code:

```
    url = 'https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statements/2000/2000_index.html'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    for a in soup.select('td[width="580"] img + a')[400:]:
    u = 'https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statements/2000/' + a['href'] 
    print(u)
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, 'html.parser')
    t = s.select_one('td[width="580"], td[width="600"], table[width="580"]:has(td[colspan="2"])').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
    print( t.split('[end of document]')[0] )
    print('-' * 80)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this script to save the data into CSV:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statements/2000/2000_index.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for a in soup.select('td[width="580"] img + a'):
    date = a.text.strip(':')
    title = a.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip(': ')   
    u = 'https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statements/2000/' + a['href'] 
    print(u)
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, 'html.parser')
    t = s.select_one('td[width="580"], td[width="600"], table[width="580"]:has(td[colspan="2"])').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
    content = t.split('[end of document]')[0]
    print(date, title, content)
    all_data.append({
        'url': u,
        'date': date,
        'title': title,
        'content': content
    })
    print('-' * 80)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
...

                                                   url  ...                                            content
0    https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statemen...  ...  Statement by Philip T. Reeker, Deputy Spokesma...
1    https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statemen...  ...  Media Note\nDecember 26, 2000\nRenewal of the ...
2    https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statemen...  ...  Statement by Philip T. Reeker, Deputy Spokesma...
3    https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statemen...  ...  Notice to the Press\nDecember 21, 2000\nMeetin...
4    https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statemen...  ...  Statement by Philip T. Reeker, Deputy Spokesma...
..                                                 ...  ...                                                ...
761  https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statemen...  ...  Press Statement by James P. Rubin, Deputy Spok...
762  https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statemen...  ...  Press Statement by James P. Rubin, Spokesman\n...
763  https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statemen...  ...  Notice to the Press\nJanuary 6, 2000\nAssistan...
764  https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statemen...  ...  Press Statement by James P. Rubin, Spokesman\n...
765  https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statemen...  ...  Press Statement by James P. Rubin, Spokesman\n...

[766 rows x 4 columns]
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

---

EDIT: For year 1998:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statements/1998/1998_index.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for a in soup.select('td[width="580"] img + a, blockquote img + a'):
    date = a.text.strip(':')
    title = a.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip(': ')   
    u = 'https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statements/1998/' + a['href'] 
    print(u)
    s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, 'html.parser')
    if not s.body:
        continue
    t = s.select_one('td[width="580"], td[width="600"], table[width="580"]:has(td[colspan="2"]), blockquote, body').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
    content = t.split('[end of document]')[0]
    print(date, title, content)
    all_data.append({
        'url': u,
        'date': date,
        'title': title,
        'content': content
    })
    print('-' * 80)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked! Since you seem to be an expert at this do you know what the issue is with the structure of this link: https://1997-2001.state.gov/briefings/statements/1998/1998_index.html and why it won't seem to run that same script (neither printing the content nor converting to the csv, and there is no error)?

Comment: So I also tried to use that script to scrape this link: https://1997-2001.state.gov/statements/2000_index.html, but nothing would run and there was no error, do you know what the differences are in the structure or what needs to change in the script?